# Sort the Main NSArray using the SubArray key value pair

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I want to sort my main array depending on the *first_name* in the array self.contacts

**Code that is used to sort the array**

```
-(void)Sort
{
     NSSortDescriptor *sdName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"first_name" ascending:YES];
     self.contacts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.contacts sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sdName, nil]]];
}
```

**MyData**

```
self.contacts = (
        {
            contact = {
                "first_name" = "Test R";
            };

            "last_met" = (
                {
                    "last_met_date" = "2014-10-09";
                }
            );
        },
        {
            contact = {
                "first_name" = "Test K";
            };

            "last_met" = (
                {
                    "last_met_date" = "2014-10-09";

                }
            );
        }
    )
```

Comment: Please add more information. Your question is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this sort descriptor:

```
descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"contact.first_name" 
                                         ascending:YES];
```

The parameter `key` is actually a **key path**, and `NSDictionary` is KV compliant. You can write stuff like: `[contacts[0] valueForKeyPath:@"contact.first_name"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking on your code it looks like that you want to sort your contacts array, which is an array of dictionaries, the solution I provide here is for that case.

You can do it like this:

```
NSArray *sortedContactsArray = [self.contacts sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *first_name1 = [obj1 valueForKeyPath:@"contact.first_name"];
    NSString *first_name2 = [obj2 valueForKeyPath:@"contact.first_name"];

    return [first_name1 compare:first_name2];
}];
```

Note, that it could be not safe and optimal, but that's just one of the ways to do it.